# Batch - Move file that start with pattern to a certain folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a list of files organized like this: test%MM%YYYY%DD.txt, for example:

```
test01201401.txt
test01201402.txt
test01201403.txt
...
test02201401.txt
test02201402.txt
...
```

I would like to create monthly-based folders like `\test%MM%YYYY` (e.g. `\test012014` or `\test022014`) and then move all the daily based .txt files into the respective folder, for example all `test012014*` files are moved to the `\test012014` folder and all `test022014*` files are moved to the `\test022014` folder and so on.
Thanks!

Comment: you say batch, but then show `/`  which are more *nix like? what OS / shell are you using, and what have you tried so far? what doesn't work,etc??

Comment: yes sorry im under windows I added / in order to show that is a directory and not a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%f in ('dir /b ^| findstr /r "^test[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.txt$"') do (
    set "filename=%%~nf"
    if not exist "!filename:~0,10!" md "!filename:~0,10!"
    move "%%~f" "!filename:~0,10!"
)
```

For every filename that matches this regex `^test[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.txt$` (a filename starting with `test`, followed by 8 digits, and ending with `.txt`), it checks if a folder whose name matches the first 10 characters of the filename (`t e s t M M Y Y Y Y`) already exists, if not it creates it, then it moves the file there.

Comment: Thanks this is perfect! The only poblem is that in this way it creates folders like this test012 and test022 but I would like to have the complete year like test012014 and test022014.. But I dont understand.. do I have to change ~0,10?

Answer (score 0):

example

```
p:\DANE\telefony\Marcin\Archiwum>..\..\move-archive.bat
move IMG-20220119-WA0000.jpg 2022\2022-01\
move IMG-20220119-WA0001.jpg 2022\2022-01\
```

code

```
@echo off
rem not %var% but !var! give us access to internal loop variable value with enabledelayedexpansion.
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem Run by scheduler script in p:\dane\telefony\marcin\move-archive.bat
rem p:
rem cd p:\dane\telefony\marcin\archiwum
FOR %%V IN (*.*) DO (
rem echo "****** %%V *********"
SET filedate=%%~tV
rem echo !filedate!
SET fileyear=!filedate:~6,4!
rem echo !fileyear!
SET filemonth=!filedate:~3,2!
rem echo !filemonth!
rem create directory as yyyy\yyyy-MM
mkdir !fileyear!\!fileyear!-!filemonth! 2>nul
echo move %%V !fileyear!\!fileyear!-!filemonth!\
move %%V !fileyear!\!fileyear!-!filemonth!\ >nul
)
```