# Command for moving versioned files

Tags: batch-file, cmd, move

Need to move versioned files having a filename starting with certain chars
eg: I have to move files with filenames starting with "CQ" to a certain folder
But the source folder consists of versioned files like

```
cq72761.xxx.2
cq72762.xxx.3
cq73237hhh1.xyz.1
cq73237hhh1.xxx.5
cq73237hhh2.xyz.1
cq73237hhh2.xxx.5
cq73238hhhh.xyz.1
cq73238hhhh.xxx.5
```

I am getting error as below

[image: error]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code, commands or screen shots which describe your problem. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29752371/batch-move-file-that-start-with-pattern-to-a-certain-folder#29757284

Comment: @MarcoKinski Thanks for your reply. My case is similar. In my case, the length of the filename is not constant.

Comment: @CKE <br>I was trying command with multiple wildcards <br/>move CQ*.xxx.* Y:\Final_Components\CF_CQ

Comment: do you want to move ALL `CQ` files? or only certain ones?

Comment: What is the result when using `move "CQ*.xxx.*" Y:\Final_Components\CF_CQ`? Please copy/paste it into the question.

Comment: @lit added as suggested.

Comment: Please try `move /Y "cq*.prt.*" "b:\test1"`. Also, please copy/paste the text of the output rather than a screenshot into the question.

Comment: @lit For move /Y "cq*.prt.*" "b:\test1" also same error as above, ie. "A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found."

Comment: What is your current directory and are there any cq*.prt* files in it?

Comment: @lit the current directory is a mapped network drive which is having CQ*.prt.* files in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you sinply want to move All CQ files:

```
move /Y cq* "Y:\Final_Components\CF_CQ"
```

if you want to move certain files, for instance ones with `xxx.` extention:

```
for %i in (CQ*.xxx.*) do move /Y %i "Y:\Final_Components\CF_CQ"
```

or without the `for` loop:

```
move /Y CQ*xxx* "Y:\Final_Components\CF_CQ"
```

If you want that for loop in a batch file instead

```
@echo off
for %%i in (CQ*.xxx.*) do move /Y "%%i" "Y:\Final_Components\CF_CQ"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: My requirement is to move versioned files of CREO software. As the source folder contains non-CREO files also, I need to restrict to the particular file extension (which will be like cq*.prt.1,cq*.prt.2 etc); <br/> I have used the command suggestion given by you but it is leading to two type of errors. 1. Syntax error and 2. Duplicates found.<br/> Please suggest how to proceed further.

Comment: @VvNair syntax error ia because you probably used the commands meant for batch file, in a cmd console. If it is in cmd, use single % i.e `%i` if in a batch file double them. I.e `%%i`

Comment: Following command worked.>> move /Y CQ*xxx* Y:\Final_Components\CF_CQ

Answer (score 0):

Using robocopy i have achieved the required result
Without logging: `robocopy <Source> <Target> CQ*xxx* /mov`
With Logging: `robocopy <Source> <Target> CQ*xxx* /LOG+:<logfile> /mov`